# Zoom In and Zoom Out for dynamic Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

This is my Zoom In and Out code:

```
function ZoomIn() {  
    var ZoomInValue =      parseInt(document.getElementById("stuff").style.zoom) + 1 + '%'  
    document.getElementById("stuff").style.zoom = ZoomInValue;  
    return false;  
}  

function ZoomOut() {  
    var ZoomOutValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("stuff").style.zoom) - 1 + '%'  
    document.getElementById("stuff").style.zoom = ZoomOutValue;  
    return false;  
}
```

This is not working correctly I want it to zoom in and out it makes the image larger which is not a pleasing zoom. Can anyone help in getting the proper zoom in and out code so that my problem can be solved or if there is a better alternative to do it?

The HTML:

```
echo'<input type="button" value="Zoom In" OnClick="return ZoomIn();" />';   
echo'<input type="button" value="Zoom out" OnClick="return ZoomOut();" />';
```

Comment: Consider to post also the involved html and/or CSS!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I have use in the past for getting a Zoom Effect on images.. Let me know if you can use is:

```
            $('#container img').hover(
                function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.stop().animate({'opacity':'1.0','height':'200px','top':'0px','left':'0px'});
                },
                function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.stop().animate({'opacity':'0.5','height':'500px','top':'-66.5px','left':'-150px'});
                }
            );
        });
```

Comment: This one contains hover effect i want to do it by clicking on a button

Answer (score 0):

I think this link is what you are looking for..

```
var currentZoom = 1;
$('button').click(function() {
    currentZoom += 0.1;
    $('body').css({
        zoom: currentZoom,
        '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + currentZoom + ')'
    });
});
```

[See it on jsfiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/VAvkL/)

Comment: Nope this one does not solve my problem my image is rotating 360 like in a virtual tour so i want to add a zoom to that rotating image

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if the below given sample code helps.

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<img src="http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="height:600;width:800;"id="stuff">

<hr>
<button type="button" id="ZoomIn">Zoom-In</button>
<button type="button" id="ZoomOut">Zoom-Out</button>
</body>
<script>
    var currentZoom = 1.0;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Resize on mouse over
        $('#stuff').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).animate({ 'zoom': 1.2 }, 400);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).animate({ 'zoom': 1 }, 400);
        });

        //Zoom in on mouse click
        $('#ZoomIn').click(
            function () {
                $('#stuff').animate({ 'zoom': currentZoom += .1 }, 'slow');
            })
        //Zoom out on mouse click   
        $('#ZoomOut').click(
            function () {
                $('#stuff').animate({ 'zoom': currentZoom -= .1 }, 'slow');
            })
    });
</script>
</html>
```